# Google Play distorting and dulling the screenshots

Tags: android, image-processing, google-play, screenshot

When I uploaded a screenshot image to Google Play, they seem to be resampling the image and dulling out the color, maybe it happens when they reduce the size. I have a 95KB image and they seem to compress it to 65KB. The image resolution stays the same, but their final version makes it look life less.

**Edit:** I just looked at Angry Birds and their screenshot is 600KB, this seems unfair.

Image in question:
https://lh3.ggpht.com/CHWDJySN2W0o8CBqSYVCZMbvtq5152xinFPLSYbFGBrFfleVccZGm68LePM2nTN6OIc=h900

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirdsspace.premium

It seems counter-productive, good screenshots attract users, and will dispel the notion Android Apps are ugly compared to other mobile OSs.

Anyone had an experience with using tools that will reduce the size and stop Google Play taking the life out of the image? Also, what tool is Google using to resample the screenshot?

Comment: Are you actually sending in JPEG images?! Don't do that.

Comment: Micheal - yes JPEG images, why does Google treat them poorly when they produce smaller sizes for most types of images.

Comment: JPEG is a lossy file format; _any_ manipulation of them at all will cause a loss in quality.

Comment: but why are Google manipulating jpeg files if they are within the file size limit, smaller files allow for responsive web pages /app store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to upload PNG files instead of JPG. PNG is a lossless format and you will not experience any deterioration in quality.

Comment: put png file sizes are huge, compared to the 100KB Jpg file, the png file is around 300KB

Comment: True but I think it's much better to have bigger images than poor quality ones. At the end of the day, people need to decide if they want to install your app or not. Poor quality image may put them off.

Comment: True but I am annoyed why Google is doing this, there is no benefit for them and they don't mention it in the docs, what they do to jpgs.

Comment: You're very right. But in the situation, you can't do much but use png.

Comment: I will approve this answer once Google Play has updated the png photo I uploaded, so I can verify PNG is the solution.

Comment: The issue in question isn't the quality of the originally uploaded file, but the way Google processes them. They even seem to ruin PNG's

Comment: And what about the file size have to be small as possible. The most of users have
a slow internet and the screenshot loading can be too long. User may quit before install.